# kafka and flink : Getting stream to webapp

Tags: web-applications, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying out kafka and flink :

- I use a flink producer to send stream tweets to kafka.
- I use several flink consumer to treat this data (atm just parsing, and keeping the main message from the tweets).
  Now I would like to display these clean messages in my web application (angular2 base).
  What would be some good practice to do this ?

If I create a basic REST webservices, I guess I will lose the streaming interest, am I right ?

Should I feed my webapp with flink data or should I send it to another kafka topic for it to serve it to the webapp ?

Thank you,

Antoine

Answer (score 1):

> Should I feed my webapp with flink data or should I send it to another kafka topic for it to serve it to the webapp ?

That's will change nothing, you 'll lose the streaming interest with the web service no ?
Have you thought about using a websocket engine ? In order to send messages to clients as a flow ?

Depending on your backend tech : 
- https://github.com/socketio/engine.io
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server
- ...